# Form is sent to back after function runs

Tags: vb.net, backgroundworker

I've got the following section of code:

```
Public Sub SendTestEmail()
    Try
        Dim Mail As New MailMessage

        Mail.Subject = "Test email"
        Mail.To.Add(smtpTXTsendto.Text)

        Mail.From = New MailAddress(smtpTXTusername.Text)
        Mail.Body = "This is a test message"


        Dim SMTP As New SmtpClient(smtpTXTserver.Text)
        If smtpCHECKssl.Checked = True Then
            SMTP.EnableSsl = True
        Else
            SMTP.EnableSsl = False
        End If
        SMTP.Credentials = New System.Net.NetworkCredential(smtpTXTusername.Text, smtpTXTpassword.Text)
        SMTP.Port = smtpTXTport.Text
        SMTP.Send(Mail)
        MessageBox.Show("A test email has been sent." & Environment.NewLine & Environment.NewLine & "To: " & smtpTXTsendto.Text & Environment.NewLine & "From: " & smtpTXTusername.Text & "." & Environment.NewLine & Environment.NewLine & "If you did not recieve an email, please check your settings and try again.", "Test Email")
    Catch ex1 As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex1.Message)
        Return
    End Try
End Sub
```

The Sub `SendTestEmail` is called inside of a Background worker.

The odd issue I'm having, as that when a `MessageBox` appears, and I click `OK` the form gets sent to the back of the screen, behind all applications ...

I've tried adding a `Me.focus`, but it gives me issues about Cross Tread violations.

Any ideas why this is happening?

Background Worker Code:

```
Private Sub BGWSendTestEmail_DoWork(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles BGWSendTestEmail.DoWork
    SendTestEmail()
End Sub
Private Sub BGWSendTestEmail_RunWorkerCompleted(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs) Handles BGWSendTestEmail.RunWorkerCompleted
    If (e.Cancelled) Then
        MsgBox("Something went wrong!")
    Else
        GroupBoxTesting.Visible = False
        Me.Enabled = True
    End If
End Sub
Private Sub SMTPButtonTest_Click_1(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles SMTPButtonTest.Click
    GroupBoxTesting.Visible = True
    Me.Enabled = False
    BGWSendTestEmail.RunWorkerAsync()
End Sub
```

Comment: I would suggest to remove messagebox from SendTestEmail method and add it into UI methods. It's better to separate UI logic from business logic. This might also remove your weird issue.

Comment: Not sure what you mean? Where else could I put it? I mean, where would the UI logic take place, within this "TEST"?

Comment: Don't display a message box on a worker thread, it has no Z-order relationship with the rest of the windows in your app.  It is also equally likely to lose and disappear behind another window, invisible to the user.  Remove the try/catch, use the e.Error property in the RunWorkerCompleted event handler instead.

Comment: Thanks for the comment Hans, I'll do a bit of trial an error, and see if I understand what you wrote here.

Comment: The problem is your calling controls from the worker thread not the UI thread - that is the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change BGWSendTestEmail_RunWorkerCompleted to something like this and remove exception handling from SendTestEmail

```
Me.Enabled = True ' Always enable form first after completed

If e.Error Is Nothing Then

            If Not e.Cancelled Then
                MessageBox.Show("A test email has been sent." _
                                & Environment.NewLine _
                                & Environment.NewLine _
                                & "To: " & smtpTXTsendto.Text _
                                & Environment.NewLine _
                                & "From: " & smtpTXTusername.Text _
                                & "." & Environment.NewLine _
                                & Environment.NewLine _
                                & "If you did not recieve an email, please check your settings and try again.", _
                                "Test Email")

                GroupBoxTesting.Visible = False 'Maybe put this also into start of method?
            Else
                MsgBox("Something went wrong!")
            End If
Else
            MessageBox.Show("Email sending failed. Exception: " & e.Error.Message)
End If
```

If you debug this program your debugger will attach exceptions in do_work method, but if you run it without debugger then exceptions are handled at completed method.

Comment: I split that long message into a bit more maintainable format. You can use old one if you like. 

I also changed If orders so that normal process is in If blocks and exceptional behavior is in else blocks

Comment: I actually came up with something similar, after Hans mentioned his comments. But thank you for this! It works perfectly now, and now I know to keep UI events out of a BG worker.

Comment: Edit, it now errors out if the SMTP settings are incorrect. It errors out right after SMTP.Send(MAIL) and it highlights the "End Sub" of "SendTestEmail"

Comment: It act like that in Visual Studio run actual program to see production behavior.

Comment: Both, upon running the debugger, the code will halt on the END SUB of SendTestEmail. This is if I purposely butcher the settings. See here: http://i.imgur.com/hpj81dT.png

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56292/discussion-between-mino-and-level42).

Comment: To remove different behavior at visual studio add following line Above SendTestEmail method: <System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute()> _

Comment: That is not the answer, that does not solve the Cross Thread Exception!

Comment: Moving messageboxes out of the background worker will remove need to Me.Focus which causes cross thread exception.